# Spinner items not displayed in android app

Tags: android, android-spinner

**main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Choose Details"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Year"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Branch"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Semester"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"/>

    <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"/>

    <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**string.xml:**

```
    <string name="app_name">SRMSyl</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string-array name="spinner">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="spinner2">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="spinner3">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

I have given my `main.xml` and `strings.xml`. I was wondering to know that why arent the spinner items getting displayed on the screen. The list is not getting displayed when i click the spinner in my device. Am i not referring to the correct spinner elements or is their something missing?

Comment: this looks fine. anyways check out the following examples
Check the following examples :

http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html http://www.designerandroid.com/?cat=4

Comment: @user2474232 do u find the solution??

Answer (score 3):

To populate the `Spinner` items directly from XML you will need to supply them with an `android:entries` value:

```
android:entries="@array/array_name"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#attr_android:entries

> Reference to an array resource that will populate the Spinner. For static content, this is simpler than populating the Spinner programmatically.

So in your case:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:entries="@array/spinner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"/>
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

If no items are displayed maybe the items are not supplied to the spinners correctly. See [Populate the Spinner with User Choices](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#Populate).

From this page there arises four questions; have you:

- Identified your spinner correctly?

> Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.**spinner**);

- Created an ArrayAdapter from your string array?

> ArrayAdapter adapter =
>   ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.**spinner**,
>   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

- Specified the layout to use when the list appears?

> adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

- Applied the adapter to the spinner?

> spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Make sure all these are performed in your Activity before the user can press the spinner button, for example in the OnCreate() method.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Ken Wolf's answer if you want to populate Spinner data dynamically, do it as below:

First Initialize the `Spinners` as below:

```
Spinner spn1  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spn1);
Spinner spn2  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spn2);
Spinner spn3  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spn3);
```

Next, Add String arrays to `ArrayAdapter` as below:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1= new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.array_spinner1);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2= new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.array_spinner2);
adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3= new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.array_spinner3);
adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Next add the ArrayAdapter to Spinner to populate list of all array data as below:

```
spn1.setAdapter(adapter1);
spn2.setAdapter(adapter1);
spn3.setAdapter(adapter1);
```